# Vertical Spacing behavior for theorems directly under sections

Tags: templates, vertical-spacing

I'm trying to use the Legrand Orange template in Overleaf. I cannot figure out why the vertical space under a section is ignored if a theorem environment is directly under it, but respected if there's text first. I've tested this by messing with the template and vertical spacing commands.

Here's a simple example, without changing anything from the temple structure.tex file:

```
\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

\section{Definitions Under Section}

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}
```

The output shows how the second definition is too close to the section (and this still happens if I incease vertical spacing for sections or theorems) [image]

Thanks in advance for any solutions to this!

Comment: Did you try `\vspace{<some length>}` between `section` and `definition`?

Comment: Yup, should've mentioned that works but I want to figure out how to get that automatically within the general structure without writing it every time.